# Image needs 2 clicks to fire a click event

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm using a Wordpress plugin to create a gallery. When you click on an image it creates a modal effect. I need to assign a link to that image to visit an external page on click, however I need to click the image twice, the first one sort of like to focus on the image (no pointer before first click). The reason for the $(document).click(function() is to check if a user clicked anywhere in the page(to fire up the modal).

```
if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-2757") || $("body").hasClass("page-id-2752")) {
    $(document).click(function () {
        var imageLink = $("img[src='https://lacostadelalgodon.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/01-la-costa-del-algodon-1.jpg']");
        imageLink.css("cursor", "pointer");
        imageLink.on("click", function () {
            window.open("http://www.vogue.com/article/this-spanish-label-makes-our-sleepwear-as-daywear-dreams-come-true");
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You are attaching event handler inside another click handler. Thus its working on second click</s>

*Remove `document` click handler*

```
if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-2757") || $("body").hasClass("page-id-2752")) {
    var imageLink = $("img[src='https://lacostadelalgodon.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/01-la-costa-del-algodon-1.jpg']");
    imageLink.css("cursor", "pointer");
    imageLink.on("click", function () {
        window.open("http://www.vogue.com/article/this-spanish-label-makes-our-sleepwear-as-daywear-dreams-come-true");
    });
}
```

Use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach

```
$("body.page-id-2757,body.page-id-2752").on('click', "img[src='https://lacostadelalgodon.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/01-la-costa-del-algodon-1.jpg']", function(){
    window.open("http://www.vogue.com/article/this-spanish-label-makes-our-sleepwear-as-daywear-dreams-come-true");
});
```

Comment: I know it does make sense and I'm sure I tried that first but it doesn't work. You can look at the gallery here: https://lacostadelalgodon.com/press-en/ The image with the link is the "Vogue" one. The only way I could make it work is with the document click.

Comment: @Sergi, Does images are loading dynamically? Are you using any plugin?

Comment: Yes, it uses a plugin called Unit Gallery, that's why I select the image with it's src attr, because I have no access to the HTML, otherwise it would be much easier.